# How to get some values in json to display?

Tags: php, arrays, json, api, codeigniter-3

I'm fetching an api that collects the number of infected people to display on the web page which can be displayed on the web page as an array but is unable to fetch some variables to display one by one. from being unable to extract the data to the end

```
$api = file_get_contents("https://covid19.ddc.moph.go.th/api/Cases/today-cases-all");
$data = json_decode($api, true);
print_r($data);
```

result :

```
Array ( 
  [0] => Array ( 
    [txn_date] => 2022-01-17 
    [new_case] => 6929 
    [total_case] => 2331414 
    [new_case_excludeabroad] => 6720 
    [total_case_excludeabroad] => 2318971 
    [new_death] => 13 
    [total_death] => 21938 
    [new_recovered] => 5255 
    [total_recovered] => 2227485 
    [update_date] => 2022-01-17 07:23:11
  )
)
```

If you want to take some value how to write ?

Comment: Are you asking how to access [Arrays](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)?

Comment: do you want to iterate over the array and print desired values?

Comment: I just want to fetch some values from the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a forach-loop to display the data here:

```
foreach ($data as $row) {
    echo $row[txn_date];
}
```

Instead of echo, you could use whatever you want to display the data, you could also add them to another variable or add html-tags around:

```
foreach ($data as $row) {
        $html = '<li>'.$row[txn_date].'</li>';
}
```